# Updating JUnit from 4.8.2 to 4.9 ExpectedException.apply issue

Tags: java, junit

I'm working on updating some project dependences to JUnit 4.9 from 4.8.2 and one of the methods on ExpectedException has changed between the two versions.

4.9

```
public Statement apply(Statement base, org.junit.runner.Description description)
```

4.8.2

```
public Statement apply(Statement base, FrameworkMethod method, Object target)
```

I'm unsure as to what to change so that the JUnit tests maintain the same functionality as they seem to be quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests should never be calling `apply` anyway. This is an internal `JUnit` method (called from the JUnit framework not tests). You should only every be calling `expect` or `expectMessage` on `ExpectedException`.

See the notes in the javadoc on usage: [ExpectedException](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html)

Comment: Apologies, the code is using a custom ExpectedException and delegating the apply method back to the normal ExpectedException. This is so some full stack traces can be logged elsewhere (I think, not my code and I'm not terribly experienced).

Comment: OK, so you will need to update the custom `ExpectedException` to take the new signature. However, since the old version is probably not using either the `method` or `target` and just passes them along you should be able to follow the same pattern using `description`.